# replace ✔ in SQL string

Tags: sql

I have one character in my string `---✔`

I tried with REPLACE function, but not working for `✔`

Example:

```
 Contractor Central Contact: abc@XYZ.au Job Title: Ref checks x 2✔ Reminder
```

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE('Ref checks x 2✔ Reminder', '✔', '');` It is working. Is this string type ?

Comment: @DaminiSuthar  yes very strange when I run like this , is working, but when I do Select replace(column,'✔','') from table. It doesn't work, column is nvarchar

Comment: What is output coming? And when you do just `select * from` what is output?

Comment: @DaminiSuthar still showing in output --✔ same, not replacing with space. I think it is not detecting ✔ this in the string

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Perhaps you need a national character string literal, e.g. `N'---✔'`?

Answer (score 0):

I had encounter something like this but while data load job

This query works well in MySQL

First of all to avoid any misconception from the database convert your varchar to binary so it gets evaluated by its binary value, then use a replace statement with again `BINARY('✔')` so it is the same value as the varchar that was converted before so it would be something like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(BINARY('Ref checks x 2✔ Reminder'),BINARY('✔'),'');
```

And you can implement it like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(BINARY(t.columnName),BINARY('✔'),'') as columnName from table t;
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.